# How to add SqlAzure retry logic to OrmLite operations?

Tags: c#, servicestack, azure-sql-database, ormlite-servicestack

I would like to make the retry logic transparent, ideally utilizing Microsoft's [Transient Fault Handling Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680899%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx), instead of wrapping every database-accessing piece of my code into a function that retries.
What I can do is creating a custom `IDbConnectionFactory`
that produces custom `IDbConnection` objects of type `MySqlAzureConnection`:

```
MySqlAzureConnection dbConn = myConnFactory.OpenDbConnection();
dbConn.Insert(new Employee { ...  });
```

I have two choices:

- Add an `.Insert()` method to `MySqlAzureConnection` to hide
  the same extension method of OrmLite, to provide my retry logic.
  Actually my `.Insert()` will contain exactly the same source code
  as in OrmLite: call `dbConn.Exec()`, but that `.Exec()` will be
  my implementation that provides the retry logic.
  The problem is that (in order to be sure that queries and writes
  in my program always use the retry logic) this way I will end up
  with copy&pasting all the 120+ methods in the 
  [OrmLite][Read|Write]ConnectionExtensions static classes,
  just to extend the behaviour of the very single `dbConn.Exec()`.
  Not sounds too good.
- Omit `using ServiceStack.OrmLite;` to make sure that the non-retrying
  implementations of OrmLite won't get called. In this case how can I use
  OrmLite? I'll have to write full namespace-qualified names all the time.
  Sounds terrible, too.

EDIT:

I realized that there's a third choice: giving up the requirement of
the retry logic being 'transparent'. In other words, admit the explicit use
of a wrapper function at every piece of code that uses OrmLite, and
implement the retry logic in that wrapper function. In fact, the [Transient Fault Handling Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680899%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx)
does the very same thing: introduces `ExecuteCommand()`, a new method
(non-standard in an `IDbConnection`) and makes the developer responsible
for using it as a high-level wrapper around any database-accessing code.

Whilst this solution sounds better than the first two, I'm still not
satisfied with it. The Entity Framework (6.0) has managed to make
this resiliency *transparent*, and I'm looking forward to a similiar
solution here. (It would be easy to wire into OrmLite's
ReadConnectionExtensions.Exec() method – if it weren't a static extension
method. Even better is an injectable module, as [done in the Entity Framework](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Connection%20Resiliency%20Spec))
.

Comment: You might be able to create a couple custom 'Write' (insert, delete, update) extension methods on your MySqlAzureConnection that use the OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider.ToInsertRowStatement()/ToDeleteStatement() etc to generate the SQL statments for Command.CommandText property.

Comment: Interested in this as well - will create a PR - however would it be as simple as to override OrmLiteConnectionFactory? @mythz would you have a view on the best way to go with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did some further research on this and it turns out that transient error handling is now built into SqlConnection under the hood from .Net 4.6.1 onwards. Therefore as a raw Ado.net SqlConnection underpins Ormlite any custom approach should be rendered unnecessary.

Dan